# Camera for Turtlebot 2 with Skeleton Tracking (2018)

Tags: kinect, turtlebot, camera, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I am new to ROS and now exploring Turtlebot 2 and I would like to add-in the skeleton tracking features for my Turtlebot.
After doing some web searching, I found that the skeleton tracking packages available such as:
http://wiki.ros.org/openni_tracker
http://wiki.ros.org/skeleton_markers#Works_Only_With_Microsoft_Kinect

They are supporting the Xbox 360 camera or Xbox 1 camera. And they have reached EOL.

Question:
What is the camera you would recommend? In Turtlebot 2, the Orbbec Astra camera is the successor for Kinect Camera, but it also means it can't work with skeleton tracking packages such as openni_tracker, skeleton_markers ...
Any recommendation of camera that can work with Turtlebot setup, but yet can work with available Skeleton Tracking ROS software packages?

Thanks a lot for your reply / reading this question.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285741/camera-for-turtlebot-2-with-skeleton-tracking-(2018)/) by [edteds](https://answers.ros.org/users/34192/edteds/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-03-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Personally I have never used Orbbec Astra camera. I don't quiet know your entire need regrading skeleton_tracking but based on the experience I have had with Kinect camera, I think they are ok for a simple skeleton tracking job. There is a certain need for calibration to build the skeleton every time the camera lost sight of human. As long as you keep the body in front of the camera, it will do the job. Also the Kinect sensor is cheap, I got a used one for 20 bucks.

---

Originally posted by [BoY](https://answers.ros.org/users/29954/boy/) with karma: 26 on 2018-04-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1